# Help with If/And

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, 2019

Running SP19 On Prem. Have a list with a column looking at type category with three options, and a completed column. I am looking at a calculated field/column in the list to filter a view with.

- 1st condition- Type A and yes
- 2nd condition Type B and Yes
- 3rd condition- Type C and complete doesn't matter.

What I have so far is:

```
=IF(AND([Validation Type]="Technical and Business Validation,[Technical Validation Complete]="Yes","Yes",IF([Validation Type]="Business Validation Only","Yes",IF([Validation Type]="Technical Validation Only","No")))
```

The filters seem to work with condition 2 and 3; but, when I add in the first statement, syntax errors. Have been trying to work this out several different ways and no success.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of `[Technical Validation Complete]` column? Choice or Yes/No??

Comment: Also, what should be the outcome/result of 2nd & 3rd conditions? "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: The data type for complete is choice. The second should be yes and the third no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `[Technical Validation Complete]` column is of type "Choice", use this:

```
=IF(AND([Validation Type] = "Technical and Business Validation", [Technical Validation Complete] = "Yes"), "Yes", IF(AND([Validation Type] = "Business Validation Only", [Technical Validation Complete] = "Yes"), "Yes", IF([Validation Type] = "Technical Validation Only", "No", "")))
```

If `[Technical Validation Complete]` column is of type "Yes/No", use this:

```
=IF(AND([Validation Type] = "Technical and Business Validation", [Technical Validation Complete]), "Yes", IF(AND([Validation Type] = "Business Validation Only", [Technical Validation Complete]), "Yes", IF([Validation Type] = "Technical Validation Only", "No", "")))
```

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Ganesh you are awesome! This saved me a ton of mental stress and fixed my problem. Thank you so very much and for also not making me feel like a dummy for the question. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!